# Assets External Source File Directory Number?

Tags: assets

When adding an external source to Assets like S3, the database doesn't store that directory. So I am unable to figure out what the file directory number is. I am using the {exp:assets:folders} tag pair with the parent_folder parameter. To use this parameter I need the file directory number for {filedir_X}. Because when using Assets on the front-end I am using Segments to changes the directory.

Is there a way to get that directory number?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this when using an external source for files, use {source_X} in the documentation. I didn't use this in the beginning because I had to no way of founding out how to get he source id number. To find the source id number go back in the external source settings and it is in the URL.

I have asked Pixel and Tonic to please add a way on the front-end to show the source and file directory id without having to find it in the EE back-end URL or in your database.